# How to convert R factor (prediction) into csv?

Tags: r, csv

I have the following factor:

```
> str(prediction)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

and I wish to get a csv of 9000 x 1 vector of ones or zeros.

I have tried:

```
write.table(prediction, file = "prediction-1-Decision-Tree-08-Oct-2013.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA, qmethod = "double")
```

but this gives me a csv with two columns and header:

```
"","x"
"1","1"
"2","0"
"3","0"
"4","0"
"5","0"
etc.
```

I wish to have no header, and just one column.

Comment: `row.names=FALSE` and `col.names=FALSE` ?

Comment: If you _only_ want ones or zeros you may also consider `quote = FALSE`, to avoid that the factor column is surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're almost there!  just add `row.names=FALSE` to your write.table call:

```
write.table(prediction, file = "prediction-1-Decision-Tree-08-Oct-2013.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA, qmethod = "double"
           , row.names=FALSE)
```

What you are seeing is not a column, but the row.names to original `R` object.  For future reference, There are two things that give away the fact that those are rownames and not data - well 3, if you count the manual ;)

- The header for that column is `""`
- The numbers are sequential, starting at 1 (which is what one would expect if there are no explicit rownames given)

Comment: row.names=FALSE and col.names=FALSE did it. Thanks.